# EditText in listview losing control

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I have added two textview(id, name), two edittext and two buttons(edit,save) in every row of listview, When edit button is clicked both edittext appears in that row(visibility is set to gone in XML) now all I want to do is allow user to add some contents in edittext and on pressing save button those contents will be reflected in textview and edittext will be disappeared again.

On edit buttons click view two edittext are appearing as expected but as soon as I type in any of the edittext they are getting refreshed. In debug mode I have found out that as soon as I am typing in Edittext getView() method called again & again and that's the reason behind refresh.

I have implemented empty onclicklistner on edittext so that when it get touched and typed it will not call getView but thats not working and I know that's a stupid attempt to solve problem.

Please tell what to do so that when I click or type in edittext it will not call getView().

Comment: What are your `ListView`s `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes set to?

Comment: fill_parent & fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

You have to off focus from xml of edittext and button